# Что лучше использовать EventBus или Otto?

Tags: java, android

Что лучше использовать EventBus или Otto?

Хотелось бы услышать ответ тех кто уже пробовал и то и другое и решил для себя что лучше. Думаю кроме меня новичкам тоже будет интерестно в будущем зайти на этот пост и прочитать дельные советы бывалых программистов.

По поводу `ЛУЧШЕ` я имею ввиду. Производительность работы, простота использования для программиста и другие факторы.

В гугле на русском языке ничего дельного не нашел

Comment: Вторая библиотека нынче `deprecated`, поэтому я бы не стал ее сравнивать. [Вот](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/COMPARISON.md) немного информации.

Comment: имхо, лучше вообще не юзать басы, я бы не хотел дебажить такой код, это как `goto`.

Comment: @post_zeew , если учесть почему создатели библиотеки Otto считают ее не актуальной, то EventBus так же является deprecated

Comment: Согласен с @katso. Такие библиотеки рушат ООП. Отладка становится болью. Навигация по коду - тоже боль.

Comment: +1 за RxJava - [ссылка на пример](http://blog.kaush.co/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вот](https://gist.github.com/mifkamaz/34ddca7ae2665037560a4c8ba1bc741b) перевод на русский статьи со сравнением EventBus и Otto([оригинал](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/COMPARISON.md))

После прочтение становится ясно что EventBus превосходит Otto как по количеству фич, так и по производительности

Answer (score 4):

Из личного опыта советую использовать `RxJava`. Все рано или поздно к ней приходят, хотя бы что-то попробовать. Одно из преимуществ то, что Вы можете работать без подписок отписок просто с синглтон классом. И если вы используете "реактивный подход" в целом, то уже нет надобности подключать дополнительную стороннюю библиотеку.

Стоит отметить, что в `RxJava1` и в `RxJava2` реализация изменилась в плане используемых классов. В случае первой версии использовался интерфейс `Action1<T>`, который во второй заменили на `Consumer<T>`. Так как первые гайды на которые Вы можете наткнуться с большой вероятностю будут описывать первую версию это поможем решить проблему.

**Пример передачи событий используя RxJava 2**

Singletone-класс

```
public class RxBus {
private static RxBus instance;
private PublishSubject<String> messages = PublishSubject.create();

public static RxBus instanceOf() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new RxBus();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void setString(String object) {
    messages.onNext(object);
}

public Observable<String> getMessages() {
    return messages;
}
}
```

Вызов экзепляра:

```
RxBus bus = RxBus.instanceOf();
```

Отправка события:

```
bus.setString("example");
```

Прием события:

```
bus.getMessages().subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull String s) throws Exception {
            switch (s){
                case "example":
                    System.out.println("hello world");
            }
        }
    });
```

Следует отметить, что если вы транслируете одно и тоже событие (в данном примере если передавать один и тот же `String`), то все живые компоненты которые на него подписаны будут его получать. Например, если у Вас есть 2 живые активности, которые отлавливают такое событие и в результате получения создают и переходят на третью активность, то последняя у вас создастся в двух экземплярах.

Учитывая этот факт Вы должны либо сразу работать с уникальными событиями, либо дополнять `RxBus` соответственным методом `unsubscribe()`.

Comment: Видимо, раз уж советовать реактивные решения, то применительно к Android это должен быть [rxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid), как гораздо лучше интегрированный в фреймворк инструмент.

Comment: @pavlofff хорошее замечание, но следуя официальной документации следует подключать обе библиотеки, так как большинство интерфейсов назодятся в пакете `io.reactivex`, которая является частья `RxJava`, а `RxAndroid` состоит из плагинов и планировщиков, которых, как говорит сама же документация "можно пересчитать на пальцах".

Comment: честно говоря без лямбд вариант с eventbus
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
выглядит более вменяемым

Comment: а вот это "Одно из преимуществ то, что Вы можете работать без подписок отписок просто с синглтон классом." откровенно не верно. Без подписок/отписок вы  не сможете работать.

Comment: аргумент за только "И если вы используете "реактивный подход" в целом, то уже нет надобности подключать дополнительную стороннюю библиотеку", т.е. что вы реализуете свой вариант event bus используя Rx https://blog.kaush.co/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/

Comment: @hardsky предложеный выше пример и является вариантом "без подписок/отписок" и он работает. Если Вы, конечно,  не считаете `instanceOf()` за такие события.

Comment: bus.getMessages().subscribe не что иное как подписка и скорей всего на onPause нужно отписаться

Comment: @hardsky так если не отписаться, то все равно работать будет и будет слушать постоянно